# SSL Certificate Not Trusted - Intermediate Certificate

Tags: ssl, nginx

When I check my website through Digicert, it says that *SSL Certificate is not trusted*

[image]

Here's the NGINX configuration

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    server_name ~. "";
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }

    # Wildcard certificate
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/STAR_mydomain_com-bundle.crt; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/STAR_mydomain_com.key; 
}
```

The `STAR_mydomain_com-bundle.crt` and `STAR_mydomain_com.key` are the only two files emailed by Comodo when I registered the SSL. So I'm not sure which file is missing in the chain.

Comment: Starting from bottom, each certificate issuer is the subject of the next one just below, except that on top you have a certificate issued by Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA where the previous subject one is Comodo RSA Domain Validation Securite Server CA. So they do not match. And your question is offtopic here as not related to programming. But go back to your certificate provider and ask it about the proper certificate chain to use, since there is a mismatch with your CA chain and your (presumed) leaf certificate signed by "another" CA.

Comment: (It would have been far simpler to provide the certificates content as text, instead of an image). You can also use `openssl verify` by providing the chain through `-untrusted` and a specific `-purpose` to check if the certificate is fit for a given use based on the chain of CA provided.

Comment: How many certificates are in `STAR_mydomain_com-bundle.crt`? You can count the blocks in an text editor.

Comment: @Robert 2 blocks for the bundle crt. Also, I find that when I test the website for SSL using COMODO's checker no issues are raised, https://comodosslstore.com/ssltools/ssl-checker.php#results (all good)

But curl and other website SSL checkers reports error.

Comment: @xybrek `STAR_mydomain_com-bundle.crt` should contain every certificate of the chain. If one is missing just copy the missing cert block at the end and it will be recognized.

Comment: Here's what I did:
`cat STAR_mydomain_com.crt comodorsadomainvalidationsecureserverca.crt comodorsaaddtrustca.crt  addtrustexternalcaroot.crt > mydomain-ssl-bundle.crt`

So the blocks in the certificate are 4 but still, I get "Incomplete, Extra certs, Contains anchor" error when checking

Comment: Using geocerts ssl checker, I get " A valid Root CA Certificate could not be located, the certificate will likely display browser warnings." whereas the certificate text can be clearly seen in the last block (same with  addtrustexternalcaroot.crt contents)

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the tip I have managed to fix the SSL problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when you register for an SSL from Comodo (e.g. via Namecheap) you get two files (in zip format):

e.g.

1. STAR_mydomain_com.crt
2. STAR_mydomain_com.ca-bundle

Combine the two files based on the instruction [here](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9419/33/installing-an-ssl-certificate-on-nginx).

So it would be

```
cat STAR_mydomain_com.crt STAR_mydomain_com.ca-bundle > STAR_mydomain_com-bundle.crt
```

To install this certificate into NGINX first do:

```
cat STAR_mydomain_com-bundle.crt SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.crt > tls.crt
```

The certificate combined here can be then used with NGINX and is valid without issues.

Comment: This worked for me. REMEMBER! When concatenating these files into a single crt file, MAKE SURE the site certificate is first listed on the file and then secondly, the certificate bundle. Nginx will throw a privatekey mismatch otherwise.

Comment: @suchislife Sorry could you expand on this? You mean the names of the file need to be the same as the website?

Comment: I've posted an answer to clarify NGINX directives. The ORDER in which you CONCATENATE is important. LEAF(certificate) to ROOT(Bundle). Once again, TOP to BOTTOM as though you were to literally Copy & Paste the contents of each file from LEAF to ROOT.

Answer (score 0):

#### For added clarification, NGINX expects 3 Directives within the `server` block:

```
ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/www_example_com_ssl_certificate_key.pem;
ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/certs/www_example_com_ssl_certificate.pem;
ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/www_example_com_ssl_trusted_certificate.pem;
```

`ssl_certificate_key` is your SSL certificate RSA Private Key.

`ssl_certificate` is the LEAF; your SSL certificate, purchased somewhere.

`ssl_trusted_certificate` expects any INTERMEDIATE(BRANCHES) and ROOT(CA) certificate TOP to BOTTOM; LEAF to ROOT. This is often the `.ca-bundle` file that comes with you SSL Certificate.

Together, these directives create the **Full Certificate Chain**.

To keep it simple, you are doing nothing more than creating a Tree; but from Leaf to Root.